# Generate xml file from city list

Tags: bash, shell

I have a city.txt file with over 1000 lines (one city name per line) , and also a format.xml file with this code block:

```
        <ss:Row ss:Height ="22">
        <ss:Cell>
           <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
           <ss:Data ss:Type="String">CITY-FROM-TEXT-FILE-LINE-1</ss:Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
           <ss:Data ss:Type="String">CALIFORNIA</ss:Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
           <ss:Data ss:Type="String">CA</ss:Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
           <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
           <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
           <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
           <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
           <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
           <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
           <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
           <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
           <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
           <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
           <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
           <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
           <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
           <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
           <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
           <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
           <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
           <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
           <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
           <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
           <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
        </ss:Cell>
    </ss:Row>
```

I need a bash script that will copy format.xml and change CITY-FROM-TEXT-FILE-LINE-1 to a the city name from the list. One code block fro each city.

Can you help me please ?

Comment: does it have to be a bash script?

Comment: so you want to create a bunch of `ss:Row`s from a city.txt file?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat city.txt | \
  while read CITY; do \
       sed "s/CITY-FROM-TEXT-FILE-LINE-1/$CITY/" format.xml; \
  done
```